# How can I do a 'git pull' within' PHP's 'shell_exec' method?

Tags: php, git, curl, deployment, permissions

I am trying to execute a PHP file that tries to run `git pull` within' PHP's `shell_exec` method.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cd /var/www/html && git pull &> log');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I've tried with other git commands, like `log` and that's returned fine. It's just `git pull` that isn't playing well.

I'm sure it's down to permissions, but I feel I have them set up correctly... maybe.

My files are located at `/var/www/html` and I am running as a `root` user *(I am running the LEMP stack image on a DO droplet - it's purely for testing and will be destroyed after)*

```
root@git-training:/var/www/html# ls -lah
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4.0K May 29 22:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4.0K May 29 22:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   19 May 28 18:38 about.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   20 May 29 20:07 contact-us.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  167 May 29 22:48 deploy.php
dr-xr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 4.0K May 29 22:41 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   42 May 29 20:55 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   21 May 28 18:28 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   32 May 29 20:43 profile.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   20 May 29 21:15 somefile.php
```

Now to test it I am doing a `curl` request from my local machine to the URL - `http://MY-DO-IP/deploy.php` and it runs but `git pull` does nothing...

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might not be working?

Appreciate any help.

Kind regards,

-- Chris

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs? Your web servers, php's, etc?

Comment: My guess that user that runs php process is wrong. When you run it through browser it ran by `www-data`...

Comment: In the directory structure you should at least have a file called `log` (based on the command before that). That would indicate to me that it is a permissions problem. What does `var_dump(shell_exec('whoami'));` produce?

Comment: @Mike My guess, work with external repo is setup through certificates or something for a user that is different from one that runs that php process.

Comment: did you try to run your script from cli `php your_script_name.php`?

Comment: Are you sure a simple `git pull` works?  Or should it be something like `git pull origin`?  Maybe it's complaining but you're not actually getting it logged?

Comment: @Mike - when I run your command, the output is `string(5) "root "`

@E_p - When I run the command via PHP on the server, it runs fine.

@pvg - There are no error logs as everything works, except just when using the `git pull` command... I am getting no output - it's not running.

@TimMorton - running `git pull origin` works just as fine as without adding `origin` to it.

Comment: You have done something very wrong if PHP is being run as root. I would fix that before anything. That's a massive security risk. Also, you can only ping one person at a time, so nobody else but me got notified of your last comment.

Comment: @Mike - Sorry I didn't know about the ping thing. As I said, I'm just messing around on a DO droplet (no intentions to go live with it) using the LEMP image. PHP does seem to be running as root as when I do `exec('whom;');` it says 'root'. Do you know how I can change it to run as another user?

Comment: @ChrisMellor I have practically no experience with Nginx. This site appears to be what you need. If not, Google it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04